# how to share a link from mobile browser using android/ios mobile share via option

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook, android-intent

I'm building a hybrid website for desktop and mobile,
I want to share a link from mobile browser through the share via option from the android mobile, so that i can share the link through multiple apps like Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Sms, Bluetooth, Google note and all the apps installed in that mobile.

Comment: So what is your exact requirement? Are you looking for an application to just share your link? it does'nt make any sense

Comment: am building a website, if the user view my website in mobile, he can able to share my link via all the app he downloaded in his mobile